# Is there a way to filter out a API by it's name in network tab - Google Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In the Google Chrome - Developer Tools Network tab, is there a way to filter out a specific API by it's name?

**Scenario:** In my application I have a API named "Notifications" (http://localhost:portnumber/api/login/notification) is called on every 10 seconds and it return the count of notifications for the logged-in user. In some cases, I don't want to see that API in the network tab.

As I aware, using the negative text filters (like `-.html -.css -.png`) we can able to filter the result by type. Like the same can I able to filter an API by it's name?

I have referred the [filtering document](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#filter), but didn't see the related information in that page.

Comment: Initially I thought to post this question on Super User, but after seeing [this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/393088/show-full-uri-url-in-chromes-developer-tools-network-tab#comment1857824_393088) from the DevTools Technical Writer, I'm posing here.

Comment: `-localhost:portnumber/api/login/notification` seems to work.

Comment: @wOxxOm I have already tried `-localhost:portnumber/api/login/notification` and `-domain:localhost:portnumber/api/login/notification`, those are not filtered out.

Comment: I've tried without the `:port`, actually, so it could be a bug in devtools treating `:` is a field separator. If I'm right, consider submitting an easy-to-reproduce bug report on https://crbug.com.